# Where does rsync keep the log file for complete and incomplete data transfers?

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync, remote-access

I want to get the IPs of all the destination devices where my data transfer using `rsync` could not be complete (or even start) as those devices are not connected to Internet or got disconnected while data transfer ...

---

My actual problem scenario is :

**rsync -t Desktop/sony.pdf home@a.b.c.d:
ssh: connect to host a.b.c.d port 22: No route to host**

and I want the list of all such IPs where the data transfer could not be complted ...

the list of all IPs like 'a.b.c.d '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do the job in perl (in command line):

```
# perl -ne '
    ($conn{$2}->{"ip"},$conn{$2}->{"started"})=($3,$1) if 
        /^(.{15}).*rsyncd\[(\d+)\]:\sconnect.*\((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\)/;
    $conn{$2}->{"closed"}=$1 if /(.{15}).*rsyncd\[(\d+)\]:\ssent\s.*\stotal/;
    END {
        print "Good:\n";
        map{
            printf "%s %-16s %s\n",
                $conn{$_}->{"started"},$conn{$_}->{"ip"},$conn{$_}->{"closed"} if
                    $conn{$_}->{"closed"};
          } sort { $conn{$a}->{"started"} cmp $conn{$b}->{"started"}
          } keys %conn;
        print "Unterminated:\n";
        map{
            printf "%s %s\n",$conn{$_}->{"started"},$conn{$_}->{"ip"};
          } sort { $conn{$a}->{"started"} cmp $conn{$b}->{"started"}
          } grep { ! defined $conn{$_}->{"closed"}
          } keys %conn;
    }' < /var/log/daemon.log
```

This could produce outputs like:

```
Good:
Apr 28 08:12:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 08:15:35
Apr 28 08:27:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 08:28:04
Apr 28 08:42:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 08:42:13
Apr 28 08:57:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 08:57:16
Apr 28 09:12:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 09:12:28
Apr 28 09:27:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 09:27:13
Apr 28 09:42:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 09:42:09
Apr 28 09:57:02 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 09:57:16
Apr 28 10:12:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 10:12:32
Apr 28 10:27:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 10:27:12
Apr 28 10:42:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 10:42:14
Apr 28 10:57:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 10:57:13
Apr 28 11:27:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 11:28:01
Apr 28 11:42:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 11:44:32
Apr 28 11:57:02 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 11:58:43
Apr 28 12:12:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 12:12:27
Apr 28 12:27:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 12:28:48
Apr 28 12:42:01 127.0.0.1        Apr 28 12:42:13
Apr 28 12:57:01 192.168.1.36     Apr 28 12:57:56
Unterminated:
Apr 28 11:12:01 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   but i am not having any file inside as deamon.log inside /var/log  !!

Answer (score 32):

You can say where the log file is (per the man page documentation):

```
--log-file=FILE         override the "log file" setting
```

Comment: What Linux distribution have you tested that? I get -> rsync: --log-file=/root/.rsyncd.log: unknown option

Comment: The feature was added in rsync version 2.6.9 (6 Nov 2006). You can see the change log at: http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-2.6.9-NEWS  As the change is so old, I would think that most any distribution that is up to date would have this feature.  I used Mandriva Enterprise Server which is based on a 2009 release of their free version.

Comment: remember to use double dash --log-file

Answer (score 9):

Logs infos are normaly sent via syslog daemon, **when rsync run in daemon mode**.

If you want to log someting when using rsync over ssh, you have to put option in command line:

```
rsync --rsync-path='/usr/bin/rsync --log-file=$HOME/.rsyncd.log' -t Desktop/sony.pdf home@a.b.c.d:
```

for saving logs in destination host or

```
rsync --log-file=$HOME/.rsyncd.log -t Desktop/sony.pdf home@a.b.c.d:
```

for saving logs in source host.

Answer (score 7):

Search for evidence of rsync in the system logs.  For example:

```
sudo grep -ir rsync /var/log
```

For that matter, you could grep / though that is overkill.